# prevent kendo ui grid popup editor from closing on insert (asp.net mvc)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im using kendo ui asp.net mvc Grid in my project.

is there a way to keep popup editor open when inserting new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, made me want to try and implement this.

Attach an event handler to the `Save` event. This should be called when the 'update' button is clicked.

```
 .Events(x => x.Save("SaveChanges"))
```

The event that closes the window is the dataBinding event of the grid so we are going to prevent that from happening.

```
function SaveChanges() {

alert("SaveChanges-Fired");

var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.bind("dataBinding",function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   })
}
```

Comment: This forum post on Telerik's website helped me do this. http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-prevent-editor-from-closing-

Comment: it keeps editor open but each time i click update it update inserted record, how can i make it insert new record on each click?

Comment: preventing the databinding is also breaking that functionality of the UI. It still inserts the records but the graph isn't actually showing them. I'm not sure how would get that done. The hacked way to solve the problem would be to place a button that will refresh the grids datasource.